# Will Amazon ECS autoscaling start and terminate Amazon EC2 servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

I set up autoscaling from the Amazon ECS service settings for my app with a minimum of 1 task and max of 4.  I'm using docker containers.

Will this spin up and terminate Amazon EC2 servers automatically?

Answer (score 3):

No, you need to set up cloud watch alarm for scaling cluster. The Auto Scaling group contains container instances that you can scale up (and down) using CloudWatch alarms. But in case of **Fargate**,
Clusters with Fargate tasks can be scaled using [Service Auto Scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/automatic-scaling-with-amazon-ecs/).

> Depending on the Amazon EC2 instance types that you use in your
>   clusters, and quantity of container instances that you have in a
>   cluster, your tasks have a limited amount of resources that they can
>   use while running. Amazon ECS monitors the resources available in the
>   cluster to work with the schedulers to place tasks. If your cluster
>   runs low on any of these resources, such as memory, you are eventually
>   unable to launch more tasks until you add more container instances,
>   reduce the number of desired tasks in a service, or stop some of the
>   running tasks in your cluster to free up the constrained resource.

You can read more about auto-scaling with ECS cluster in [Tutorial: Scaling Container Instances with CloudWatch Alarms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch_alarm_autoscaling.html).

You can scale manually using this approach:

- Open the Amazon ECS console
- From the navigation bar, choose the Region in which your cluster
  exists.
- In the navigation pane, choose **Clusters** and select the cluster to
  scale.
- On the Cluster: name page, choose **ECS Instances**.
- Choose **Scale ECS Instances**.
- For **Desired number of instances**, enter the number of instances to
  which to scale your cluster and choose Scale.

See: [Scaling a Cluster - Amazon Elastic Container Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scale_cluster.html)